# passing 2 dimensional array and return 1 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

```
public class magicSquare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mySquare = {{2,7,6},
                            {9,5,1},
                            {4,3,8}};

        System.out.print(columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(mySquare));
    }
                                           //***********************//
    public static int getSumOfColumn(int[]  /*[] array, int index*/) {
        int sum = 0;                //********//
        int[] t = getColumn(array  /*, index*/);

        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + t[i];
            System.out.print(t[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        return sum;
    }

    public static int[] getColumn(int[][] array, int index) {
        int[] result = new int[array[1].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array[1].length; i++) {
            result[i] = array[i][index];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(int[][] array) {
        int arrayLength = array[1].length;
        int previousValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            int value = getSumOfColumn(array, i);

            if (i != 0) {
                if (previousValue != value) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            previousValue = value;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This code works fine if you uncomment all the comments. But what I'm trying to do here is pass in a 2D array into `getColumn` method and returning it in a 1D array which then gets passed into `getSumOfColumn`. `columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum` then will check to see if all columns are equal 15 and return `true`, else `false`. And how would I do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why you can't just uncomment that code, and what the challenge of summing a column is specifically, as well as whether you're trying to have `getColumn` flatten the whole array or select a column from it. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a lot of errors in your code:

1. Delete your comments. Not the code inside of them, just the `/* */`.
2. If I were you, I won't create a variable to set the length of the first column in your multidimensional array. I will put it in the loop:

   for (int i = 0; i < array[1].length; i++){}
3. If you pass 2 variables to the method `getSumOfColumn` and you just have 1 parameter in the declaration of this method, it won't work. You also have to declare the `index`. Also, if you pass there a variable which has a multidimensional array you can't declare it like a simple array.
4. If you try to set previousValue in an `if` statement, you have to include your `previousValue = value` in an `if-else` statement because, if not, it always will set the `previousValue` like `value`.
5. You never compare if your number it's 15.

In my opinion, the code have to be like this:

```
public class magicSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mySquare = {{2,7,6},
                            {9,5,1},
                            {4,3,8}};

        System.out.print(columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(mySquare));
    }



    public static int getSumOfColumn(int[][] array, int index) {

        int sum = 0;                
        int[] t = getColumn(array, index);

        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + t[i];
            System.out.print(t[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        return sum;
    }

    public static int[] getColumn(int[][] array, int index) {
        int[] result = new int[array[1].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {

            result[i] = array[i][index];
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static boolean columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(int[][] array) {

        int previousValue = 15;
        boolean correct = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < array[1].length && correct == true; i++) {
            int value = getSumOfColumn(array, i);

            if (i != 0) {
                if (previousValue != value) {
                    correct = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(correct == true){
           return true;
        }
        else{
           return false;
        }
    }
```

If I didn't missunderstood your question, I think that you want to sum all the columns for each row in your multidimensional-array and then compare them if the number of this result its equals to 15.

I think it will be easier to do it in a double loop, one inside another, to through all the rows and columns and compare them there but I think with the code that I put above it have to works.

With double loop I mean:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array[1].length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
  {
    //Your code to make your sum
  }
//Your code to compare if your sum its equals to 15
}
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!